# Pandas converting price with symbols ("," , "-") to integer

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to convert a price to int, in the price column characters such as "," and "-" are included

I used `apply` + `lambda` + `replace`, there is no error but it seems not to be changed yet. how can i remove all characters "," after that change to int?

```
df.loc[:, '수출건수':'무역수지'].apply(lambda x : x.replace(',',''))
```

and

```
df.loc[:, '수출건수':'무역수지'].astype(int)
```

error = invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,721,193'

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weSAf.png)

Comment: Could you type the code you tried to use?

Comment: you could try using `.str.replace()` instead of `.replace()`

Comment: df.loc[:, '수출건수':'무역수지'].apply(lambda x : x.str.replace(',','')) -- It works! thank you but i still have problem with changing to int value. same error.

Comment: `df['수출건수':'무역수지'] = df['수출건수':'무역수지'].astype(int)` do that after replacing values.

Comment: you have to reassign it back to the data frame: `df["new_col"] = df.loc...`; currently it's calculating what you want and returning it (not modifying the row in-place)

Comment: thank you guys! Solved  =  df[['수출건수','수출금액','수입건수','수입금액','무역수지']] = df[['수출건수','수출금액','수입건수','수입금액','무역수지']].astype(int)